# Map strategy to calculate mean over JSON array of objects

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON array of objects that looks like this:

```
{
    "recipes": [    
    {
        "name":"recipe-name-1", 
        "ingredients": [
            { "amount": 300, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-1" },
            { "amount": 250, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-2"},
            { "amount": 100, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"recipe-name-2", 
        "ingredients": [
            { "amount": 350, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-1" },
            { "amount": 50, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-3"},
            { "amount": 120, "unit": "g", "ingredient": "ingredient-4"}
        ]
    }
```

and so on.

I'm trying to calculate, for each ingredient, the average amount of it throughout the different recipes. What would be the best way of achieving this? I was thinking about constructing a `Map` of ingredients indexed by the name of the ingredient. As the ingredients are iterated through, if the ingredient is not in the unique ingredients map then it is added, otherwise the amount of the ingredient is increased. Finally, the amount is divided by number of times the ingredient was found (do I have to explicitly keep count?). Do you think this is a viable solution?

Comment: That is the simplest approach, should work. What seems to be the issue then?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur thanks for the reply! No issue really, but since I'm trying to improve the quality of my Python coding lately, I wanted to see if anyone could give me any input on a more efficient/elegant solution.

Comment: In my opinion, this approach is fine for such a simple usage

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all inputs and then collect all necessary information in two default dicts, which you will use in the final step to calculate the averages.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
       
counts = defaultdict(int)
amounts = defaultdict(int)

recipes = data['recipes']
for recipe in recipes:
    for ingredient_info in recipe['ingredients']:
        ingredient = ingredient_info['ingredient']
        counts[ingredient] += 1
        amounts[ingredient] += ingredient_info['amount']
        
average_amounts = {}
for key in counts.keys():
    average_amounts[key] = amounts[key] / counts[key]
    
print(average_amounts)
```

**Output:**

```py
{'ingredient-1': 325.0,
 'ingredient-2': 250.0,
 'ingredient-3': 75.0,
 'ingredient-4': 120.0}
```